# How to integrate a landing page with a Vue SPA?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So, I've built an SPA with Vue. We hire a designer to create a landing page. The landing page looks great. It shows some info about the app and there is a "Sign in" button that does nothing at the moment.

The landing page does include CSS and Javascript (jQuery etc) that I don't, and don't want to, use in the Vue app.

So the question is: Is it possible to include the landing page code in my Vue project without loading landing page JS/CSS if user is already signed in?

Plan B for me is to host the landing page on mydomain.com and the app on app.mydomain.com. This will work I guess, I see others do this. But it would be nice to know my possibilities

Comment: Can you share your solution for this? I am running into the same issue currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some search and didn't find exact solution to your issue, however it seems that this is doable. I have some concerns regarding the head part of the page, but this is a way to start:

1. Create new Vue component that will include all the HTML code (body only) that you need + install (with npm) and import all needed js files, including jQuery, in that component.
2. Make sure, that you configure this component as [lazy loaded](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) in vue-router - so all your html and scripts will be separated from the app.

From there Vue should do the job - you will get your page where needed and other routes will be inside the app.

Comment: Note: This answers my question, but I'm not sure if I will go for this solution. There are som issues with SEO when the landing page and the app uses the same index.html. There is also an advantage to have landing page in separate repo/CMS when considering editing/updating one but not the other. I will most likely go for plan B described in my question